# R Filling all observations after first occurrence with that observation in longitudinal data

Tags: r, longitudinal

I have data that is set up as on the left in this table, but I want to generate data on the right:

| ID | A | --> | ID | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |  | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |  | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 |  | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 |  | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |  | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |  | 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |  | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |  | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |  | 2 | 0 | 1 |

I want to generate the column B, which is 0 until the first occurrence of a 1 in column A, and then fill the proceeding observations with 1 from that first observation in A, by ID. I'm not even sure where to start.
If anyone can help I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <-
  structure(list(
    ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
    A = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-9L))

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(B = cummax(A)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 9 x 3
#>      ID     A     B
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     0     0
#> 2     1     0     0
#> 3     1     1     1
#> 4     1     0     1
#> 5     2     0     0
#> 6     2     1     1
#> 7     2     0     1
#> 8     2     0     1
#> 9     2     0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This worked, thank you!

Comment: Great! If you believe this answer was helpful for you, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe we can try

```
transform(
  df,
  B = +ave(A==1, ID, FUN = cumsum)
)
```